# I am requiring image file through fs.readfile, I want to store the binary data in MySQL table. How can I do it

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I created a table register3.
while signup, the user given details are stored in mysql table and by default I want an image from local folder as profile image,and save the path to mysql

when ever user uploads the image of his wish,the default image need to be updated by the uploaded image. and the image must be stored in folder of path given and path in mysql should also be updated.

code:

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Your code snippet is not working.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add details of what happens when you do this? Error messages, DB schema etc., would help us understand the problem better.

Comment: @AndriiPryimak it will not work as stack snippets don't provide node js environment

Answer (score 0):

Why do you store images in database?

```
var mime = require('mime'); // npm install mime
fs.readFile('public/images/2.jpg', { encoding: 'base64'}, function(err, data){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        // get the mimetype
        var filemime = mime.lookup(filepath);
        // make string data
        var base64= 'data:' + filemime + ';base64,' + data;
        // do somthing with base64 string
    }
});
```